# Running function until pearson correlation function of >0.99 is achieved

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pearson-correlation

I have the following code:

current code:

```
import math
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import linregress

c1_high = 98
c1_low = 75
c2_high = 15
c2_low = 6
c3_high = 8
c3_low = 2

def mix_gen(number):
    flag = 0
    container = []
    y_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

    while flag < number:
        c1 = np.random.uniform(c1_low, c1_high)
        c2 = np.random.uniform(c2_low, c2_high)
        c3 = np.random.uniform(c3_low, c3_high)
        tot = c1+c2+c3

        if 99.99 <= tot <= 100.01:
            flag += 1
            container.append([c1,c2,c3])
    return container

def average(x):
    assert len(x) > 0
    return float(sum(x)) / len(x)

def pearson_def(x, y):
    assert len(x) == len(y)
    n = len(x)
    assert n > 0
    avg_x = average(x)
    avg_y = average(y)
    diffprod = 0
    xdiff2 = 0
    ydiff2 = 0
    for idx in range(n):
        xdiff = x[idx] - avg_x
        ydiff = y[idx] - avg_y
        diffprod += xdiff * ydiff
        xdiff2 += xdiff * xdiff
        ydiff2 += ydiff * ydiff

    return diffprod / math.sqrt(xdiff2 * ydiff2)

def corr_check():
    while True:
        mixes = mix_gen(5)
        mixes_C1 =[item[0] for item in mixes]
        mixes_C2 =[item[1] for item in mixes]
        mixes_C3 =[item[2] for item in mixes]
        mylen = [1,2,3,4,5]
        c1_r = pearson_def(mixes_C1, mylen)
        c2_r = pearson_def(mixes_C2, mylen)
        c3_r = pearson_def(mixes_C3, mylen)

        if c1_r >0.99 and c2_r >0.99 and c3_r>0.99:
            print(mixes)
            print (c1_r)
        else:
            continue

corr = corr_check()
print(corr)
```

This code provides me with effectively (when converted to a dataframe) the following output:

```
    C1    C2    C3    sum   range 
1   70    20    10    100     ^
2   ..                        |  
3   ..                        |
4   ..                        | 
5   ..                        |
6   ..                        |
7   ..                        |
8   ..                        |
9   ..                        |
10  ..                        |
11  90                        _
```

I require the sum of each row to be equal to 100 and each column to have an r^2 value (Pearson Corr.) to be > 0.99.

However, the complexity and number of iterations required renders the problem almost impossible to solve. Is there a better way of achieving this goal instead of trying to rely on the initial random number generation for all three components C1, C2 and C3?

Comment: When you say "11 strings each with 3 items" do you mean 11 rows? This is not very clear...

Comment: Yes, I mean 11 rows 3 columns. Sorry for not making this clear.

Comment: There are some other things that are unclear about your question. It's difficult to answer, because you didn't post an example of the function that returns your data, then you ask if this function can achieve your desired output or if you need an other function. Please go to this link and consider editing your question after reading the instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have updated the question for clarity.

Comment: If you want three numbers with a sum of 100, why do you generate three random numbers and check for that?
It will be far more efficient to generate just two random numbers and define the third as c3 = 100 - c2 - c1.

Comment: This is because I want to extend the method for at least 10 different numbers.